# How can we add sub query in a Spring Data JPA @Query annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How can we add sub query in a Spring Data JPA **@Query** annotation ?

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Foo a WHERE ( LOWER(a.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:searchTerm, '%')) ) :optionalQuery")
    Page<Foo> findBySearchTerm(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, @Param("optionalQuery") String optionalQuery, Pageable pageRequest);
```

where **optionalQuery** will be set in **DAO**.

Example: String optionalQuery = "AND a.code=" + code;

Comment: It is not allowed.

Comment: FYI The JPA API has no such `@Query` annotation. That is "Spring Data JPA" which is not the same. JPQL (the query string that goes in there) is defined in docs on the internet, or the JPA spec

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743011/springdata-is-it-possible-to-have-subqueries-in-the-query-annotation