# Nested SQL in @Query tag is not working properly

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Suppose I have a table which contains all the accounts of user and type.
I want to make a Jpa Repository method which returns an array of total number of each type of user (USER, ADMIN, MASTER).

Here is how I did it in JpaRepository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE account_role='USER'),"
                        + "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE account_role='ADMIN'),"
                        + "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE account_role='MASTER')"
                        + "FROM account LIMIT 1",
            nativeQuery=true)
public List<Integer> getTotalAccountType();
```

The code executed fine, but the result wasn't what I expected.

Result:
`[2]`

Expected result: `[2,10,30]`

Any idea how would I use nested SQL with JPQL? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743011/springdata-is-it-possible-to-have-subqueries-in-the-query-annotation

Comment: Side note - possibly better query: `SELECT account_role, COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE account_role IN ('USER', 'ADMIN', 'MASTER') GROUP BY account_role` (although you'd need to return a different type from your method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning `Object[]` rather than a `List<Integer>`. I think returning `List<Integer>` would indicate multiple rows of an `Integer` value are being returned, whereas you're getting back one row with multiple `Intger` columns.

From the resulting `Object[]` you would pull out the first value (indicating a row). This should be another `Object[]`, which will have your values in the order returned.

You can also remove that last `"FROM account LIMIT 1"` line, as it has no bearing on the result.

I would recommend casting all of this to an object though. As seen here -
[How to return a custom object from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328063/how-to-return-a-custom-object-from-a-spring-data-jpa-group-by-query)

Answer (score 2):

If repository method returns List of Integers it means that query result row contains an Integer value. But you expect to get sequence of Integers in one row.

You can get same result different way:

```
@Query(value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE account_role=?", nativeQuery=true)
public Integer getTotalAccountType(String role);
```

and then:

```
Integer userCount = repository.getTotalAccountType("USER");
Integer adminCount = repository.getTotalAccountType("ADMIN");
Integer masterCount = repository.getTotalAccountType("MASTER");
```

or if you have mapped entity:

1. create `Pair<K,V>` class with constructor `Pair(K key, V value)` or use it from any [external library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html)
2. repository method based on hql query

   `@Query(value="select new javafx.util.Pair(a.accountRole, count(a)) from Account a group by a.accountRole")
   public List<Pair<String, Integer>> getRoleCountList();`
3. convert repository result to a `Map<String, Integer>` in service

   `javafx.util.Pair<String, Integer> result = repository.getRoleCountList();
   Map<String, Integer> map = result.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(r-> r.getKey(), r-> r.getValue()));`