# Spring boot JPA subquery with round brackets expression

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am new with Spring JPA. I have a table, try to join it with a custom table and convert this query to JPA query:

```
SELECT *
from delivery_missions dm 
inner join (
  select di.delivery_mission_id , GROUP_CONCAT(di.delivery_spot_id) as spot_list, GROUP_CONCAT(di.reception_no) as recp_no
  from delivery_items di GROUP by di.delivery_mission_id 
)  as items on items.delivery_mission_id = dm.id 
GROUP by dm.id
```

Below is the query I'm writing but I have problem when

```
@Query(value = "SELECT dm, ml, items " +
      "from DeliveryMission dm " +
      "inner join MissionLog ml on ml.deliveryMission.id = dm.id " +
      "inner join ( " + //error here with left parenthesis
      "  select di.delivery_mission_id , GROUP_CONCAT(di.delivery_spot_id) as spot_list, GROUP_CONCAT(di.reception_no) as recp_no " +
      "  from delivery_items di GROUP by di.delivery_mission_id  " +
      ")  as items on items.delivery_mission_id = dm.id ")
```

My solution is try to use with nativeQuery (or convert to mybatis). But type of JPA query look better for me.

Edit 1: My question is how to express this **(** and **)** in JPA query.

Edit 2: Relate to my question about subquery in JPA Spring data. 
[No, it is not possible to have subquery in the select clause in JPQL query.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743011/springdata-is-it-possible-to-have-subqueries-in-the-query-annotation).

Comment: missing comma after `items.recp_no`

Comment: @sidgate thank you, my actual query is longer so I remove some part and post to here.

Comment: obviously you have syntax error in your query. you need to share complete query to identify the issue. also share what error you see

Comment: You are mixing JPQL and SQL, that isn't going to work. The part in the join is a SQL query not a JPQL query. Just write a plain SQL query and let that do the job. Or rewrite the inner part to JPQL as well.