# Spring JPA join parent with child object into custom DTO

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA entities, Dashboard and Permission.

```
public class Dashboard {
  private String id;
  private String name;
```

```
public class Permission {
  private String id;
  @Enumerated(STRING)
  private PermissionType type;
  @ManyToOne
  private Dashboard dashboard;
```

I want to select all Dashboards with their Permission types(only list of string values). So I created DTO.

```
public class DashboardWithPermissionTypesDTO {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String creator;
  private List<String> permissionTypes;
}
```

I am able to query similar object(same as DashboardWithPermissionTypesDTO, but instead of List it has String only)
*@Query("SELECT NEW dto.DashboardWithPermissionTypesDTO(d.id, d.name, d.creator, p.type) FROM Dashboard AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN Permission AS p ON p.dashboard.id = d.id")*

**Is it possible to query result straight to DashboardWithPermissionTypesDTO object?**

Thanks !

Comment: A `subselect` should do the trick, as it can return a list of values

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?
[I do not thing it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743011/springdata-is-it-possible-to-have-subqueries-in-the-query-annotation). Also can not see it in documentation.
SELECT NEW dto.DashboardWithPermissionTypesDTO(d.id, d.name, d.creator, (SELECT NEW Permission(p1) FROM Permission AS p1)) FROM Dashboard AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN Permission AS p ON p.dashboard.id = d.id